# Portal users cannot run User object reports - insufficient privileges

Tags: community, reporting, sharing, portal

I have a Customer Community Plus site with portal users using Customer Portal licenses.  I want the portal users to  run User object reports so they can see last login, etc.  Portal users are still getting "Insufficient Privileges" when trying to run these reports, even though I think I've done all the necessary settings.

They are able to run other standard and custom object reports without problems.  The user license type is Customer Portal Manager Custom.

I know that in the past, a user needed View Setup and Configuration permission to run User reports, and that portal profiles didn't have this permission.  However, I thought I read recently that portal users now had the ability to run User reports.  Am I mistaken?

Here's what I've done:

The user profile has Run Reports permissions.  (The users access all reports through a Visualforce page, so we have not set the View Reports in Public Folders permission.)

In Sharing Settings, enabled External Sharing Model.

In Sharing Settings, on the User object, set the Default External Access to Private.*

In Sharing Settings - User Sharing Rules, set up a Read Only sharing rule for All Customer Portal Users.

On the report folder, share the folder to All Customer Portal Users as Viewer.

On the report itself, I'm using the Username, First Name, Last Name, Created Date and Last Login.  I'm filtering on Account.Name.  The portal user profile has Read permission to the Account object.

*This doesn't seem right, but that is what this article says:
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Why-do-Portal-Reports-receive-an-Insufficient-error-or-are-missing-columns&language=en_US

Comment: There's some Dashboard/Report permission settings on Profiles, have you tried those?

Comment: Yes I checked those settings.

Comment: OWD on External Users doesn't have to be set to Private. You may want to look at these 3 links 1) https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_sharing.htm&language=en, 2) https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_owd_external.htm&language=en_US and 3) https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_owd_external_setting.htm&language=en_US.

Comment: @crmprogdev Well that's interesting because the article I mentioned says that the OWD does need to be set to Private:https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Why-do-Portal-Reports-receive-an-Insufficient-error-or-are-missing-columns&language=en_US

Comment: If you follow the link at the bottom of the page you've referenced, you'll discover more information. I suspect that article was written before the External Sharing OWD model was available. I recommend you read the 3 references I've cited from the SF Help pages which were ultimately linked from that article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run User reports we need Run Reports” AND “View Setup and Configuration” in profile..

I think for portal users “View Setup and Configuration” permission is not enabled in profile.

So portal users cannot run report on users. They will have limited access to the organization.

Please [see the docs](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_administrative.htm&language=en_US) for more details.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_administrative.htm&language=en_US

Comment: I am mistaken - I had thought our portal users were able to run User reports before, but it looks like they never were able to.  So it looks like @bahnu Manesh is correct in that View Setup and Configuration is still needed.

I was confused to see the Default External Access available for the User object in the OWD, which seems to bypass the need for View Setup and Configuration.